# Outer measure defined by a continuous and bijective function

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, reference-request, integration

This problem is from [K.T. Smith's Primer of Modern Analysis](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387907971):

> Let $\psi: \mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}^d$ be continuous and one-to-one on an open set $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ and define $$\nu(A) := \mu(\psi(A))$$ for $A \subset \Omega$, where $\mu$ is Lebesgue measure. Show that $\nu(A)$ defines an outer measure on $\Omega$.

I have no idea how to prove monotonicity with the given conditions:

> For $A \subset B \subset \Omega $, $\nu(A) \leq \nu(B)$

Any ideas/hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A \subseteq B \subseteq \Omega$, then $\psi(A) \subseteq \psi(B)$. Now use monotonicity of the Lebesgue-measure. You don't even need injectivity for this.

Comment: You are right, thank you.